# Use .NET Framework 4.5 dll in Framework 4.0 project

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, .net-4.5, compatibility

I am working on a project which is build on dot net 4.0 and i have a need to use some .dll's which are released with dot net framework 4.5. Is there a way to include and use them on my project? If Yes then please suggest the way.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a 4.5 dll in a 4.0 project. Think about upgrading your 4.0 project or downgrading the 4.5 project. Upgrading will probably the easiest, because if the 4.5 is using 4.5 features (if not, why make it a 4.5 project...), you will have to rewrite them to 4.0.

Comment: I am not trying to use 4.5 project's dll, but dll's which Microsoft released with dot net 4.5 framework.

Comment: Check if they have a earlier version of the dll, if not upgrade your project to 4.5.